# Determination of coefficients matrix in one dimensional Kronig-Penney Model

Tags: matrix, physics

In page 169 , Chapter 7, from book "Introduction to solid state physics (Eighth Edition)" by Kittel,  there are 4 equations as below. Without need to any additional physics information I just want to reach to equation 21.a.
This equation is the result of the matrix determination of the coefficients of (A, B, C, D).
The matrix coefficients can be written as:

```
matrix = {{1, 1, -1, -1}, {I k, -I k, - q, q}, {E^(I k a), 
E^(-I k a), -E^(-q b + I g ( a + b)), -E^(
 q b + I g ( a + b))}, {I k E^(
 I k a), -I k E^(-I k a), -q E^(-q b + I g (a + b)), 
q E^(q b + I g (a + b))}};
Det[matrix]-----------> cannot reach to Eq.21.a
```

off course for preventing any problem rising up from capital letters I choose: `K->k, Q->q, k->g` but unfortunately the determination cannot reach to the Eq.21.a
(even though I have used `Simlify, Factor, Collect or....` for the final result of the determination!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is ExpToTrig:

```
matrix = {{1, 1, -1, -1}, {I k, -I k, -q, q}, {E^(I k a), 
    E^(-I k a), -E^(-q b + I g (a + b)), -E^(q b + 
        I g (a + b))}, {I k E^(I k a), -I k E^(-I k a), -q E^(-q b + 
        I g (a + b)), q E^(q b + I g (a + b))}};
FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[Det[matrix]]]

4 I E^(I (a + b) g) (2 k q (Cos[(a + b) g] - Cos[a k] Cosh[b q]) + 
    (k - q) (k + q) Sin[a k] Sinh[b q])
```

This is the product of two terms. For this to be zero, the first term, (i.e., 4 I E^(I (a + b) g)) cannot be zero, and so the second one must equal zero. Thus

```
2 k q (Cos[(a + b) g] - Cos[a k] Cosh[b q]) + 
    (k - q) (k + q) Sin[a k] Sinh[b q] == 0
```

which looks like the desired form.

Comment: I had used `ExpToTrig` before `FullSimplify`